# Sidescrolling puzzle video game on Steam where you can be dismembered and bring yourself back to normal, required to solve puzzles

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Tip of my tongue thing, but somewhere in 2020, I ran into a Steam game where you played a girl on an island (at a camp?) who I think is looking for her missing friend. I downloaded the demo to try it out, and ran into my usual issue with puzzle games, that I have a low level of frustration and found myself looking up answers. If I recall correctly, the character has three "buttons", one to jump, one to pick up/throw things, and one to regenerate. When she regenerates, all of her severed limbs disappear as they go back to her. I remember one of the puzzles involved her picking up an object and throwing it to dislodge an object in the trees. A later puzzle had the same thing, but there were no convenient objects, so you had to bump her against an obstacle to get a severed limb to throw. In another puzzle, you had to injure her down to just being a torso to make her the right weight to get through a particular balancing log puzzle. You didn't have to have the limbs nearby to regenerate them.

At least in the level I was playing in the demo, it was night time, and might have been raining. I think there may have been bonus items you could pick up that looked like donuts. I'm sure they probably actually have some sort of effect in the game itself, or they might have just been bragging rights. I don't remember if there were actual enemies other than the environment in the game. It was possible to "die" by drowning, or by taking one more injury when you were a torso, although it just took you back to an earlier checkpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like ***[The MISSING: J.J. Macfield and the Island of Memories](https://store.steampowered.com/app/842910/The_MISSING_JJ_Macfield_and_the_Island_of_Memories/)*** (2018).

> J.J. scours Memoria Island to find her best friend, who has gone missing during a camping trip. However, this island was like a nightmare: no matter how many times she sustains fatal injury, she couldn’t die, and instead is able to revive herself back to normal. J.J. ventures into the depth of the island as she drags her decapitated body along, enduring the pain.
>
> Her limbs may sever, her neck may break, she may go through severe burns, but... In order to save her best friend, she puts her own body and life on the line, reviving infinitely, as she presses forward. Why did she go missing? What is going on in this world? All of these mysteries shall be revealed when the game is cleared.

The video review below provides a good description of the core gameplay mechanic, and having looked at some other gameplay videos, I can confirm that there are collectible items of some sort which resemble donuts.

> While the environmental puzzles are initially fairly basic, it's not beofre long that *The Missing's* biggest gameplay wrinkle reveals itself: J.J.'s body is able to regenarate after suffering all but the most grizzly of fates. J.J.'s ability to come back from near-death is a curse that's crucial to solving the bulk of the puzzles in *The Missing*. Using body parts to knock objects out of trees, or to act as counterweights, as a couple of examples. It enables an undeniably grim, yet also incredibly fun and satisfyingly inventive gameplay loop, as you induce a variety of impairments on J.J. at each roadblock in order to puzzle your way through them.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you.